# result not accurate using inner join 2 queries

Tags: mysql

I want to join 2 query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT kdbaes1, kdsatker, 
                FORMAT (ABS(SUM(rphreal)),0) AS pagu 
FROM budget 
WHERE thnang='2013' AND jnsdok1 IN('202','203') 
GROUP BY kdsatker 
ORDER BY kdbaes1, kdsatker;
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT kdbaes1, kdsatker, 
                FORMAT (SUM(rphreal),0) AS realisasi  
FROM real 
WHERE thnang='2013' AND jnsdok1='301' AND kdmakmap LIKE '5%' 
GROUP BY kdsatker 
ORDER BY kdbaes1, kdsatker;
```

I try to join these query, but the result is not accurate in rphreal column

```
SELECT DISTINCT budget.kdbaes1, budget.kdsatker, 
                FORMAT (ABS(SUM(budget.rphreal)),0) AS rpbudget, 
                FORMAT (SUM(real.rphreal),0) AS rpreal 
 FROM budget 
 INNER JOIN real ON budget.kdsatker=real.kdsatker
 WHERE budget.thnang='2013' AND budget.jnsdok1 IN('202','203') AND
       real.thnang='2013' AND real.jnsdok1='301' AND real.kdmakmap LIKE '5%' 
 GROUP BY kdsatker  
 ORDER BY kdbaes1, kdsatker;
```

need help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making a guess based on what I think you are trying to achieve...

```
  SELECT DISTINCT budget.kdbaes1, budget.kdsatker, 
                    FORMAT (ABS(SUM(budget.rphreal)),0) AS rpbudget, 
                    FORMAT (SUM(real.realisasi),0) AS rpreal 
     FROM budget 
     INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT kdbaes1, kdsatker, 
                FORMAT (SUM(rphreal),0) AS realisasi  
      FROM real 
      WHERE thnang='2013' AND jnsdok1='301' AND kdmakmap LIKE '5%' 
      GROUP BY kdsatker
     ) real on real.kdbaes1 = budget.kdbaes1 AND real.kdsatker = budget.kdsatker 

     WHERE budget.thnang='2013' AND budget.jnsdok1 IN('202','203') 
     GROUP BY kdsatker  
     ORDER BY kdbaes1, kdsatker;
```

It appears you are trying to do a SUM against two separate tables in your JOIN example.

What I've done is taken your second query and made it a subquery to perform the SUM of the real table.   Then, we use this sub query to join with the budget table...

Comment: thanks alot Sparky..., i try to modify your query at line 3 with just real.realisasi AS rpreal , and work greatly accurate. THANKS...

Comment: @bonnetdenny you need to stop using `DISTINCT` in cases where you don't know why you're using it.  At best you are wasting the server's time checking a result-set for distinctness when it's impossible for it not to be distinct, and at worst, you're masking inefficiency or logical errors and potentially getting incorrect answers.  `DISTINCT` is *very* unlikely to be appropriate with `GROUP BY` or aggregate functions like `SUM()`.  Don't use it unless you understand the exact reason why you need it.

Comment: @michael thanks for the information. yes, I remove distinct and the result is same. sorry if my english is bad :)